# group_concat multiple rows where given condition

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables (User,  User_usergroups , usergroup). I would like to get a list of user who has usergroup equal to "member" and other groups (group_concat) belonging to this user. How do I do that?

I got the first part of the query, but **I could not get other groups, aggregated groups of this user** (I like to use group_concat to concatenate other groups in one field.

```
SELECT user.userId, (group_concat(group_.name)???)
FROM User_ user join Users_UserGroups userGroups
on user.userId= userGroups.userId 
join UserGroup group_ on userGroups.userGroupId = group_.userGroupId
WHERE group_.name="member";
```

Assume that is the 3 tables

[image]

The outcome will be

[image]

Many thanks for your great help.

Comment: This is a bad data example. You don't need the second table 'User_usergroups'. Just store the usergroup ID in the User table. That's better practice, and will make your query scripts easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my query is so complex and it has down vote from the administrator or someone. I wish whoever did this could add their comment to my query so that, in the future,  I will know what I need to do to clarify my question to the community or make my question better.  Here is the answer to my question.

1. First retrieve the list of userId.
2. Then join this    "member" table with other tables to find the result from the list of    retrieved ID (step 1).
3. As we aggregate the name of the groups, we need to use  groupby.

Keywords to resolve this problem is to use an alias for subquery or nested SQL

```
select member.userid,  member.screenName, group_concat(member.name)
 from (SELECT User_.userid userid, User_.screenName screenName , UserGroup.name name
      FROM UserGroup
           JOIN Users_UserGroups
               ON UserGroup.userGroupId = Users_UserGroups.usergroupid
           JOIN User_  
         on Users_UserGroups.userId = User_.userId  
      WHERE UserGroup.name = "member")member
        JOIN Users_UserGroups
      ON member.userid = Users_UserGroups.userId
      JOIN UserGroup
      on UserGroup.userGroupId=Users_UserGroups.userGroupId  
 GROUP BY member.userid;
```